# How to encode parameter in ajax request?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I have a select field ,

```
<form:form id="mediaForm" method="post" role="form">
 <table>
 <tr id="state" style="display: none;">     
                <td>
                    <form:select path="sCode" id="sCode"
                        onchange="getAllLists(this.id,'${contextPath}/main/getList.do','dCode','aCode')">
                        <form:option value="" label="--- Select ---" />
                        <form:options items="${state}" />
                    </form:select>
                </td>                            
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form:form>
```

On click of this field, another list is being called. Now,when I intercept this request and change the value of state, say, selected by user = 03, to 04, no error is displayed.
I want to encode    `var val = $('#' + new_id).val();` and decode it on the controller so that nobody can make changes in between? Kindly suggest. Tried encodeURIComponent but that encodes url and I want to encode values state = 01 ;

```
function getAllLists(new_id, url, second_name,
        image_value) {
    var val = $('#' + new_id).val();

    $.ajax({
                url : url,
                dataType : 'json',
                data : {
                    state : val
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    $('#' + image_value).empty();
                    $('#' + image_value)
                            .append(new Option('Select...', ''));
                    $.each(data.list, function(arrID, group) {
                                $('#' + image_value).append(new Option(
                                                group.desc, group.code));

                            });
                    $('#' + image_value).val("A");

                }
            });
}
```

Some sort of parameter pollution attack.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well : your concerns is about security.

HTTPS is already doing the encryption job.

If you don't use HTTPS, the problem of encryption on the client side without a key given by a third party is that this way isn't private and thus not secure.

Everyone can access the code given by the server to the client.
This means that the ciphering key given by the server could be seen and therefore, the man in the middle would just need to replicate the encryption with the value that they want you to request.

Eventually, you could try to give the ciphering key to the client the first time it connects to the server and use it all over the connection after that. It mitigates the problem but it doesn't wipe it out.

Hint for cyphering: a salted sha256 sounds nice to me.